# Angular Looped HTTP Request Map Value to Responses

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

In my service class I am looping an http get request and using rxjs forkJoin to combine all the responses into an observable which I return to my component.  For each response that comes back I need to add two properties to the json (readySystem which is an object and serviceType which is a string).  The value of each of these is different for each iteration of the loop.

How do I keep/store/retain the values for both and and map/add them to the correct response?

With the way I've attempted to do it below, the values for both are the same in every response returned in the final observable.

```
  getServices() {

  for (var x = 0; x < this.service.items.length; x++ ){
        var num = Object.keys(this.service.items[x].links).length;

         for (var key in this.service.items[x].links) {
            var systemName = this.service.items[x].systemName;
            var environment = this.service.items[x].environment;
            var server = this.service.items[x].server;
            var port = this.service.items[x].port;
            var linkName = this.service.items[x].links[key];
            var serviceType = key;
            this.observables.push(
            this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/myapi/get/service?server=' + server + '&service=' + linkName)
            .map((res:Response) => { 
                var output = res.json()
                for (var obj in output) {
                    if (output.hasOwnProperty(obj)){

                        var readySystem = new System(systemName,
                         environment,
                         server,
                         port,
                         linkName);

                    output[obj].System = readySystem;
                    output[obj].serviceType = serviceType;
                    }
                }
                return output;
        })
            );
        }
        };
        return Observable.forkJoin(this.observables);
};
```

**Update**: With the suggested code changes provided in the answer below, I get output like:

```
0: Array(33)
1: System
    systemName: "my system"
    environment: "my environment"
    etc.
2: "myservice"
3: Array(35)
4: System
   etc.
5: "myotherservice"
```

However, what is needed is:

```
0: Array(33)
 0: Object
  > System
      systemName: "my system"
      environment: "my environment"
      etc.
   serviceType: "myservice"
 1: Object
  > System
      systemName: "my system"
      environment: "my environment"
      etc.
   serviceType: "myotherservice"
 etc.
1: Array(35)
 0: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add these values to fork using Observable.of

```
function getObsevrables(observables, readySystem, serviceType) {
   return Rx.Observable.forkJoin([
     Rx.Observable.of(readySystem), 
     Rx.Observable.of(serviceType), 
     ...observables
    ]);
}

getObsevrables([Rx.Observable.of(1), Rx.Observable.of(2)], 
           {ready: true}, 'type1')
   .subscribe(x=>console.log(x))
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to update your code.

```
getServices() {

for (var x = 0; x < this.service.items.length; x++) {
  var num = Object.keys(this.service.items[x].links).length;

  for (var key in this.service.items[x].links) {
    var systemName = this.service.items[x].systemName;
    var environment = this.service.items[x].environment;
    var server = this.service.items[x].server;
    var port = this.service.items[x].port;
    var linkName = this.service.items[x].links[key];
    var serviceType = key;

    var readySystem = new System(systemName,
      environment,
      server,
      port,
      linkName);

   // getObservables([Observable.of(1), Observable.of(2)], readySystem, serviceType).subscribe(x => console.log(x));

    this.observables.push(
      Observable.combineLatest(
        this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/myapi/get/service?server=' + server + '&service=' + linkName)
        .map((res: Response) => {
          var output = res.json();
          return output;
        });
       }, 
       Observable.of(serviceType), 
       Observable.of(readySystem)
    )
   );
}
}
```

Comment: thank you.  I understand what the function is doing but what is the purpose of {ready: true} and when and where should I be calling the function from?

Comment: in a loop you create an array of observables that will do http call and as I understand you create two variables for each forkJoin - readySystem and serviceType. So you just add them to to observable array using Observable.of and do the same return as you do now.

Comment: my forkJoin is occuring in my return statement outside of my inner and outer loop.  I believe I need to add the two variables within my inner loop to each of the individual observables before they are pushed onto my observable array.

Comment: Sure. My point was you can mix in forkJoin future data received via http and existing data with Observable.of

Comment: When I add the function call with console.log prior to where I call push on my observables array, I can confirm I see the values I need to capture being output to the console.  However, I can't figure out why im still not seeing how to correctly join the values with everything else getting added to the array.  My final output still does not have these two fields.  I'll paste my current changes soon.

Comment: can u update the question with the latest code, so i can see what is not working?

Comment: its already updated above.  The console.log on the subscription of getObservables outputs during each iteration of the loop and has content such as:  [System,"service1",1,2].  The value of these first two fields are correct but I dont need the 1 or 2.  Furthermore, when I console.log again after the final results get sent back to my component from return Observable.forkJoin(this.observables) these values are not displayed in the results.

Comment: thank you. This helps.  However, to be more clear I need these two fields added to each object element in each array.  The results now come out as:  0: Array(33) 1: System 2: myservice 3: Array(35) 4: System 5: myotherservice.  What I need is 0: Array(33) 1: Array(35) etc. where each object in each array has a field of serviceType and another for readySystem.  I've tried many ways over the last couple days and even when I get the fields added where they are needed the values being populated are not correct due to async nature of observables.

Answer (score 0):

It may be a simple classic JS closure issue. When all asynchronous calls (`http.get`s and `Observable.forkJoin`) are resolved, all function scoped `var`s (*x*, *num*, *key*, *systemName*, *environment*, *server*, *port*, ... etc.) within `for` loops are set to their last value. The easiest solution would be to use ES6 block scoped `let` or `const` declarations.

So try to change your code to something like:

```
for (let x = 0; x < this.service.items.length; x++ ){
  let num = Object.keys(this.service.items[x].links).length;

  for (let key in this.service.items[x].links) {
    let systemName = this.service.items[x].systemName;
    let environment = this.service.items[x].environment;
    let server = this.service.items[x].server;
    let port = this.service.items[x].port;
    let linkName = this.service.items[x].links[key];
    let serviceType = key;

    let url = `http://localhost:3000/myapi/get/service?server=${server}&service=${linkName}`;
    this.observables.push(this.http.get(url)
      .map((res:Response) => { 
        let output = res.json();
        for (let obj in output) {
          if (output.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {

            let readySystem = new System(systemName,
              environment,
              server,
              port,
              linkName
            );

            output[obj].System = readySystem;
            output[obj].serviceType = serviceType;
          }
        }
        return output;
      }
    ));
  }};
  return Observable.forkJoin(this.observables);
};
```

and in general, there is no reason not to use [new ES6 features](http://es6-features.org) when coding with Angular 2/4.

You could also rewrite your first `for` loop using `Array.forEach()` function (I assume that `this.service.items` is an array because of its *length* property):

```
this.service.items.forEach(item => {
  let num = Object.keys(item.links).length;

  for (let key in item.links) {
    let systemName = item.systemName;
    let environment = item.environment;
    let server = item.server;
    let port = item.port;
    let linkName = item.links[key];
    let serviceType = key;

    let url = `http://localhost:3000/myapi/get/service?server=${server}&service=${linkName}`;
    this.observables.push(this.http.get(url)
      .map((res:Response) => { 
        let output = res.json();
        for (let obj in output) {
          if (output.hasOwnProperty(obj)) {

            let readySystem = new System(systemName,
              environment,
              server,
              port,
              linkName
            );

            output[obj].System = readySystem;
            output[obj].serviceType = serviceType;
          }
        }
        return output;
      }
    ));
  }};
  return Observable.forkJoin(this.observables);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a closure problem. Based on your original code:

```
for (var key in this.service.items[x].links) {
    var systemName = this.service.items[x].systemName;
```

here you may think that you're creating a new `systemName` variable each time the block is executed. Indeed, the variable is created once and it only gets assigned the new value each time the block is executed. The difference is important because below you make an asynchronous call `http.get`:

```
this.observables.push(
          this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/myapi/get/service?server=' + server + '&service=' + linkName)
            .map(res => { 
              var output = res.json()
              for (var obj in output) {
                if (output.hasOwnProperty(obj)){
                  var readySystem = new System(systemName,
```

here the callback inside the `map` is not executed immediately within the loop when `systemName` has the proper value. It just gets stored in memory for later execution (when `http.get` returns a result). The stored body of the callback doesn't carry `systemName` value, only a reference to the variable.

Now, each time the loop executes, it assigns a new value to `systemName` and stores away a callback. By the time the loop ends, the value of `systemName` is the last value assigned by the loop.

Sometime later, the `http.get` requests start completing, the stored callbacks are executed, they read `systemName` and they all get that same last value. This is what you're experiencing.

The easiest fix is actually creating a new `systemName` variable for each block execution. This can be achieved by using `let` instead of `var`. So just using `let` for all the relevant variables will fix the issue:

```
let systemName = this.service.items[x].systemName;
let environment = this.service.items[x].environment;
let server = this.service.items[x].server;
let port = this.service.items[x].port;
let linkName = this.service.items[x].links[key];
let serviceType = key;
```